# How update PHP on Mac 10.9

Tags: php

I just installed PHP 5.5.9 on my machine, but when I gone to the info.php it still said PHP 5.3.13 the default version.

How I fix that ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOIQu.png

Comment: Do you have mamp installed?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the new version has not overwritten the old version and if the new version has been installed successfully in your mac, it may have installed in a different directory (therefore the path to phpinfo will differ).

If installed in xampp or mamp you need to find phpinfo in the relevant directory for each in the application folder. For example yourname/Applications/XAMPP......

Comment: I installed on server apache on mac os 10.9 , I don't use xampp or mamp on my machine. How do I know the right path, or how can I fix the problem?

Comment: You will need to point your httpd.conf configuration to use your new mod_php library.. You can also find the path to your current php install by:  echo $_SERVER["PATH"];